# Run command when holding a key and clicking on a text in vscode API extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to trigger a command when I hold a key or multiple keys together and then click on a text.
I use this selected text later on to do some job.
From my understanding, there is no such thing as "click" shortcut in vscode, so I cant use that.
I did find that vscode.window.onDidChangeTextEditorSelection is triggered when I click on a text, but how do I now determine if i have key holding down?

Comment: select the text, then press the key binding and set a `when` clause to only be active when there is a selection

Comment: Thats how I have it now, but I would like to try and add such a functionality

Comment: you can't customize the mouse clicks